# Reading from application.properties: Attribute value must be constant

Tags: java, spring-boot

In the below-given code I get the compilation error `Attribute value must be constant`. How to deal with it?

```
@Component
public class ScheduledTasks {

    @Value("${example}")
    String message;

    @Value("${update.rate}")
    final static long rate;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = this.rate)
    public void update()
    {
        System.out.println(this.message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have *final static* rate. Try to remove these modifiers.

Comment: @Jens: at the line `@Scheduled(fixedRate = this.rate)`

Comment: @JanKhonski: Ok, I removed `final static`. Still getting the same error mesaage.

Comment: this.rate -> rate is not object field, but class field

Comment: @JanKhonski: So, how to access it properly?

Comment: I believe this is correct solution for above question but not complete. if you have refreshScope and you need to refresh property using actuator, this won't work, you have to use @Value and global var. I am looking for that solution.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Change to:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRateString = "${update.rate}")
public void update()
{
    System.out.println(this.message);
}
```

Comment: In application.properties I have this: `update.rate=5000`

Comment: It works fine. No idea why this answer was downvoted.

Comment: it's not work for me: `org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "update.rate"`. how to fix it?